# Customizing the circular seek bar

Tags: android

I am having very hard time experimenting the CircularSeekBarExample got from :- https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar . I am trying to control the rotation of the seek bar according to a value but I am not able to understand how it is functioning. I am providing you the code below. Anyone please let me know what the following code is doing in this example.Thanks!

My code: -

```
 * Sets the progress.
     * 
     * @param progress
     *            the new progress
     */
    public void setProgress(final float progress) {
        if (progress == mProgress) {
            return;
        }

        if (progress == 1) {
            mOverrdraw = false;
            mProgress = 1;
        } else {

            if (progress >= 1) {
                mOverrdraw = true;
            } else {
                mOverrdraw = false;
            }

            mProgress = progress % 1.0f;
        }

        if (!mIsInitializing) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you use a std ProgressBar with a custom progress Drawable?

Comment: @pskink Because I have to show the animation like in the example .

Comment: @pskink can you provide me some another alternative to achieve the same.